# Python: Convert a list into a normal value

Tags: python

I have a list

```
a = [3]
print a
[3]
```

I want ot convert it into a normal integer

```
print a
3
```

How do I do that?

Comment: -1: What integer does the list `[1 2 3]` convert to?  You have an element of a list that already is an integer.  Are you asking how to get the first element out of a list?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
a = a[0]
print a
3
```

Or are you looking for `sum`?

```
>>> a=[1]
>>> sum(a)
1
>>> a=[1,2,3]
>>> sum(a)
6
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is not clear.  If `a` has only one element, you can get it by:

```
a = a[0]
```

If it has more than one, then you need to specify how to get a number from more than one.

Comment: In the case of one element, unpacking can not be used?

Answer (score 2):

I imagine there are many ways.

If you want an int() you should cast it on each item in the list:

```
>>> a = [3,2,'1']

>>> while a: print int(a.pop())

1
2
3
```

That would also empty a and pop() off each back handle cases where they are strings.

You could also keep a untouched and just iterate over the items:

```
>>> a = [3,2,'1']

>>> for item in a: print int(item)

3
2
1
```

Answer (score 2):

To unpack a list you can use '*':

```
>>> a = [1, 4, 'f']

>>> print(*a)

1 4 f
```